# getWindow().addFlags() in android

Tags: java, android, flags

I have some class files of an Android App, I have code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        getWindow().addFlags(557056);
        getWindow().addFlags(4194304);
        getWindow().clearFlags(4194304);
    }
```

Need to know which is the flag represented by this number

1. 557056 ?
2. 4194304 ?

please help me in this weird case.

Comment: those .class files are left behind off my coworker for __some reasons there raised an incompatibility__ between he and I _so he left me on this spot_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
4194304 -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT

Gonna edit this answer when I find `557056`.

Comment: People with __#.#K__ reputation show __slang__ to  new comers like me or other and only point the cursor on -1 vote button, but but like you with low reputation take your time to find solution of Question and Answer it, thanks a lot Man!, BTW waiting for ___557056___

Comment: Thanks a lot @LogicalError, I'm not being able to find `557056`, maybe you can help me answering these questions:

**1. Which is the main layout of that Activity? (i.e. Relative, Linear...)**
**2. Do you notice some changes if you remove `getWindow().addFlags(557056);`?**
**3. What's the purpose of that Activity?**

Maybe you can ask your coworker to see if he remembers.

Comment: `557056` could be the result of few flags e.g. `getWindow().clearFlags(FLAG_1|FLAG_2)`